# Can anyone identify this (possibly Italian) uniform?

Tags: military, identification, uniform, italian

[image: Believe it may be my grandfather]Can anyone identify this Military uniform for me? My guess is it is Italian, possibly somewhere between 1850 - 1907.
May be from Salerno Campania Italy?  Please help!

Comment: Hi. Is there any writing on the back?

Comment: Any other background you can provide?

Comment: No, unfortunately! No writing on the back. We are thinking it may be our grandfather who was born 1881 in Italy.

Comment: Hello do you speak Italian because if so i can give you some good sources because i don't understand them.